# How to redraw images pixel-by-pixel in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

Pretty much what the title says. Conversion adds artifacts, while I need an exact copy, but only of the image itself, stripping away absolutely everything else that may or may not exist in the original file. So, I guess I need to somehow pre-render and then recreate the image one pixel at a time, but I don't have even a faintest idea as to how. Googling didn't get me farther than conversion and refreshing, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Conversion doesn't add artefacts, save in a non-lossless format does (generally). What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: (png, bmp and tiff are commonly available / lossless)

Comment: Please post examples images of before and after and what commands you are using to convert the image. You have not given us enough information to help you.

Comment: @Blackhole, I'm trying to make sure the image file uploaded contains only the picture itself. No EXIF, no other metadata, no concatenated payloads, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to strip all EXIF, GPS, IPTC, author, copyright and colour profiles from an image is to use **ImageMagick** which is available on all Linux distros and macOS and Windows.

At the command line, you would do:

```
convert input.jpg -strip output.jpg
```

If you want to do that with PHP, you can use the **Imagick** equivalent:

```
bool Imagick::stripImage ( void )
```

which is documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.stripimage.php). So that would look like:

```
// Load input image and strip everything
$image = new Imagick('start.jpg');
$image->stripImage();

// Output result
$image->writeImage('result.jpg');
```

Another, perhaps simpler and lighter-weight, way is with `exiftool` (which is *"just a simple"* **Perl** script, rather than a massive package like **ImageMagick**) like this:

```
exiftool -all= YourImage.jpg
```

You can also "shell out" from PHP using `system()` to run these commands if you find that easier.

---

If you are absolutely paranoid about this, you could convert to an intermediate format that doesn't support metadata at all, such as `NetPBM` format ([Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) and then back to JPEG, like this:

```
convert YourImage.jpg -strip pam:- | convert pam:- result.jpg
```

If you are wondering why I still used `-strip` above, it is because NetPBM does support comments so I wanted to get rid of them. If you are wondering why I chose PAM format instead of PPM, it is so that it works for PNG files that may have 4 channels (i.e. RGB and transparency).

---

You can check what information is still contained within an image using:

```
jhead -v YourImage.jpg
```

Or:

```
exiftool YourImage.jpg
```

Or, you can find all text-like strings in your image and use `grep` to look and see if anything you specifically don't want has slipped through:

```
strings YourImage.jpg | grep -Ei "copyright|latitude|longitude|author"
```

Comment: Even if the image is recreated using the same encoder which was used in the first place, this will change the information content; see comment by Blackhole

Comment: @symcbean That is not correct. The command `exiftool -all= start.jpg` does not re-encode the image. Try it. Take an image with some metadata, and calculate a hash over all the pixels (excluding the metadata) with `convert start.jpg -format %# info:` Now strip the image with `exiftool` like this `exiftool -all= start.jpg` and re-check the hash and you will see the pixels are unchanged.

Comment: @Mark Setchell
What I need is strip away not just conventional metadata, but also whatever may have been  concatenated, like in that famous rarjpeg trick with concatting an archive to an image: if you open it as jpg, it shows an image correctly, and if you open it as an archive, it opens the archive correctly.